# Where to store API token, user/pass etc

Tags: api, token, credentials

So I have an webpage. That webpage accesses an API be it with basic auth, oAuth, Digest, whatever. I have to send over some sort of authentication to the API endpoint to another service. Let's pretend it's the Facebook OpenGraph API.

Facebook issued to me credentials in order to use it's API. Where do I store those credentials to be safe from external attacks? I've always just put them in my server side code like the API documentation tells you to do. Is that safe enough? I'm not worried about internal abuse, I'm worried about external attacks.

Where do I put my web applications authentication credentials that it will use to access other services where they will be safe from external attacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question seeing as mashups using several other services are becoming ever more popular. But the unfortunate fact is that you really cannot put such credentials in a practical place, where they are perfectly safe from external attacks. Here are some options:

1. Keep them in the source code. An attacker could get access to the source code through misconfiguration of the server, a weakness in the server software. Or (s)he could gain access to the filesystem on the server or intercept the network traffic between the server and Facebook.
2. Keep them in a database external to the server. But where do you keep the credentials for the database such that your code can access it? You have simply moved the problem to another set of credentials and if the database is accessible outside the local network, you have actually increased the attack surface.
3. Keep them in a file on the server. Now the attacker will have to gain access to the filesystem or intercept network traffic. So this is more secure than the previous options.

Comment: So all out apps rest in D: on the server and as such IIS and the users running our server application obviously have read write to D as well. I was thinking of sticking them in a config file somewhere in the C drive or in a location on D that is outside the folders where our web applications live. That way at least a bad configuration wouldn't ever generally expose the credentials via a URL. It would have to be someone getting file access, which at that point, pretty screwed anyway.

Comment: Exactly, I should have mentioned that number 3 is only safer than 1 in the case where the file is kept outside the webapp folder structure :-)

Comment: File on server much like `app-configs`. Before App Settings and App Configs, we would keep all settings in DB *except* DB creds which would be in an ini file. All good suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about external attacks and are at all security-minded, you should not store the credentials in your app. Store the credentials on the server. Your application should prompt the user for credentials when they need to authenticate.

After authentication, if you want to preserve the user's logged in state, set cookies, either session cookies that expire when the browser session ends or permanent cookies that do not expire.

Comment: But the credentials are not the users credentials. They are the credentials for my server to use an API to access another server. They are the same for all "users". By application I mean, web application. All of this code I am speaking of is server side code.